# How to draw with OnPreviewGUI?

Tags: unity

I want to implement custom preview for GraphViz files.

I created CustomEditor stub for that based on this beautiful gist: https://gist.github.com/prodigga/53ab658e1a818cd4ddfd#file-meshfilterpreview-part2-cs

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Inspector for .SVG assets
/// </summary>
[CustomEditor(typeof(DefaultAsset))]
public class GraphVizEditor : Editor
{
    public override bool HasPreviewGUI()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnPreviewGUI(Rect r, GUIStyle background)
    {
        var path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(target);
        if (path.EndsWith(".gv"))
        {
            var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            texture.SetPixel(1, 1, Color.green);
            GUI.DrawTexture(r, texture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see green preview area, but preview keeps having gray background:
[image]

How to fix this and actually draw custom texture to a preview area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to call Texture.Apply():

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Inspector for .SVG assets
/// </summary>
[CustomEditor(typeof(DefaultAsset))]
public class GraphVizEditor : Editor
{
    public override bool HasPreviewGUI()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnPreviewGUI(Rect r, GUIStyle background)
    {
        var path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(target);
        if (path.EndsWith(".gv"))
        {
            var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            texture.SetPixel(1, 1, Color.green);
            texture.Apply();
            GUI.DrawTexture(r, texture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to create a new texture asset every time the preview GUI is updated! Cache & reuse that asset.